# Eclipse Android emulator command line option -tcpdump

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, tcpdump

In Eclipse, Run Configurations, I added additional emulator command line option "-tcpdump emulator1.cap" and it started to capture emulator's network traffic which can be opened by Wireshark. Cool!

Now I wonder how to capture only certain host IP address somehow? I could use Display filter but file gets too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running tcpdump directly on the device's command line. Then you can specify arbitrary filters and options as shown in the man page for tcpdump.

Then, for example:

```
adb -e shell tcpdump -w  /sdcard/capture.pcap host 10.0.2.2
```

When you're done:

```
adb pull /sdcard/capture.pcap
```

Make sure your emulator instance has enough sdcard space for the capture.

Comment: "adb -e shell tcpdump -s 1500 -w /sdcard/capture.pcap host
 10.0.2.2" was even better to avoid "Packet size limited during Capture". Thanks